# PHP Frontcontroller

Tags: php

I dont't want to use any framework, but I need a Frontcontroller,  Where I can get HELP?

Comment: not here unless you refine that question

Comment: You can implement a lot in a front controller. Be more specific.

Comment: On a sidenote, the [Google Search Results for FrontController+PHP](http://www.google.com/#q=frontcontroller+php) look like HELP, so does the [pattern description in POEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html)

Comment: You could also just use [http://twitto.org/ - A web framework in a tweet](http://twitto.org/) though actually, no, you shouldnt but it's Friday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend building a dynamic invocation front controller. This is what the frameworks use. Here is a link to get started.

http://www.phpwact.org/pattern/front_controller

This book has a great chapter on Presentation Patterns during which he covers the front controller pattern.

PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice, Third Edition (Expert's Voice in Open Source)

http://amzn.to/d3eU0r

Comment: The book "PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice" is really just great - for intermediates like me rather hard to read but worth the time

Answer (score 1):

1. You should configure your mod rewriting. All requests should be go to index.php. And not domain part should be send to the GET parameter. For example: example.com/tratata/tratata. 
   `print_r($_GET)` should contains 'tratata/tratata';
2. Create class, which will be explode this GET parameter. It is your FrontController.
3. Create class tratataController.
4. Load class by get Parameter.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a framework and look at the implementation of their FrontController. Figure out how it works and build your own.

That said, why on earth would you not want to use a framework? The only reason I can think of is that you want to know how it works. And for that just google and look at existing sources.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue, so I made my own. It's tiny, as the name suggests, and (hopefully simple to use. You just need to make sure that the correct Apache rewrite rules are in place. You can find the source on GitHub. https://github.com/samuelwilliams/Tiny-Front-Controller

Comment: The github link has 404'd