# Php page calling

Tags: php, indexing

What is the best way if i want do something like these;

I call it page calling.

I have an index.php which will run the config.php

And i want to have ***index.php*** as my core then do something like

```
index.php?customer=home  or index.php?customer=viewaccount

index.php?admin=home  or index.php?admin=updateproduct
```

then call the particular php file eg. home.php , viewaccount.php

Best regards
I really appreciate yours help.=)

Comment: uhm.. this is quite outdated. nowadays you use something like '/customer/viewaccount'. and if this is an issue for you you better check a MVC framework.

Comment: do you mean redirecting via GET variables? I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. the code snippets really depend on what you want to achieve. you'll have to provide some more data on what you actually want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Frontcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053285/php-frontcontroller)

Comment: You can also read this : http://www.technotaste.com/blog/simple-php-front-controller/

Comment: @yi_H Most frameworks do what the OP describes under the hood. It's mod_rewrite that makes the URLs "pretty".

Comment: @Juhana: *sigh* I'm perfectly aware of that.

Comment: @yi_H Why is it then "outdated"? There's nothing in the OP's post that would suggest that he *wouldn't* use pretty URLs after the underlying engine works.

Comment: @Juhana: there's also nothing in the OP's post that suggest that he *would*. I thought it's *worth* mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about a design pattern known as the [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).

It is certainly possible to implement your own front controller, but almost every PHP framework will have this capability already. I recommend you try Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mix admin and puclic areas in the same script.
So, for the public area you can do something like

```
<? 
if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
  $name="index"; 
} else { 
  $name=basename($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 
} 
$file="pages/$name.htm"; 
if (is_readable($file)) { 
  include($file); 
} else { 
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  readfile("404.html");
} 
?>
```

and then address customer pages like this `index.php?home`, `index.php?viewaccount`

Comment: Just be aware of Remote/Local file inclusion vulnerabilities when writing code like that. index.php?page=/etc/passwd or index.php?page=www.myEvilScript.com/evil.php

Comment: did you notice basename() function usage?

Comment: Oh sorry I actually didn't see it ^_^ But I thought I'd still make it aware

Answer (score 0):

Best is to check the `$_GET` parameter against an 'whitelist' array of allowed script names. After that, you can just include the file.

```
if ( in_array( $_GET['admin'], array( 'home', 'updateproduct' ) ) ) {
    include( $_GET['admin'] . '.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I couldn't be bothered to comment all of the answers here so I'll say it to you, even though this post will probably get put down as its not a direct help.

You need to be very careful when including files from a POST or GET request. Just be aware of Remote/Local file inclusion vulnerabilities when writing code like that. index.php?page=/etc/passwd or index.php?page=www.myEvilScript.com/evil.php

Many people can get hacked this way and you don't want that to happen to you.

Always sanitize your data, so stripslashes($_GET['admin']); or whatever method you want to use.

Comment: I am curious, what is stripslashes($_GET['admin']) for?

Comment: it would strip any slashes from the url so if you had index.php?admin=/MyInclude.php or something it would strip the slashes.

Comment: this function actually strips only backslashes

Answer (score 0):

The name for this pattern is a front controller.

You can implement the multiplexing on the webserver (e.g. using mod_rewrite) or in your PHP code.

Here's how **NOT** to do it:

```
 <?php

 require_once($_REQUEST['customer']);
 require_once($_REQUEST['admin']);
```

C.