# 404 page when no match found

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i have this rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\ /?].*HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^(home|contact|about|submit|search)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=home&cat=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=home&cat=$1 [L]
```

What i want is:

- if user types something which is not matching last three conditions i want to show a 404 error. At present it loads home page. So i am check `$_GET['page']` in there. I donot want to check in php.
- do you have anything to improve my rewrite rules or any additions?

please help

Comment: Redirecting to a 404 page is a really bad practice

Comment: what do you expect the first rule to do? (The `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]` one)

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is ultimately routing to **index.php** (Front-end Controller Pattern), I suggest dropping the the `mod_rewrite` and using:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Then parse the URL in **index.php** and handle routing accordingly.

This will take some rewriting, but will be more flexible in the long run.

Read more about [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) and [Front-Controllers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053285/php-frontcontroller).

Comment: thanku. this technique used by frameworks? please tell me how i get url send to "index.php" so that i can use it in `parse_url()`

Comment: Yes. Most frameworks use FEC. `FallbackResource /index.php` will send any request that doesn't have an existing resource to **index.php**. Add it to **.htaccess** (or vhost if you can) and remove all the rewrite lines.

Comment: Whatever was passed in the query string (i.e. after `?`).

Answer (score 0):

You may use mod rewrite to add argument to your web page index.php, then treating them in the php page possibly sending back a error page (as in cakePHP).  that keeps only ONE rule.

```
 RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?argument=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, in the MVC model, only the controller is called by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ErrorDocument`whit location page

```
ErrorDocument 404 /erreur_404.html
```

Comment: thanku. but i was want to do in mod_rewrite. but i liked Front-Controllers in PHP told by Jason