# Admin function with one PHP config file

Tags: php

This might be hard to explain but I am looking for the best method of having one or a group of config files so if I need to update something its a little easier to do.
I have wrote a PHP application that has a sub folder for the admin side off the root folder and includes folder that is sub folder off the root folder as well .(see below)

[image]

the include folder has database config files, loads common variables and so forth. the problem is the path for the admin files that call for the database connection are obviously different than the files in the root folder.
so I started this but now I wonder if there is a better method than the route I am going.

```
    `if($adminfile=="yes")
    {
     require('../includes/database/connect.db.php');

    }
    else{
     require('includes/database/connect.db.php');

    }`
```

I would really appreciate some advice, should I scrap this idea and have 2 location for the config file?  Part of me hates to include in all the standard code $adminfile="no" I keep thinking is there a better way.

How do others solve this problem?

Comment: you could just reference it once with `require('./includes/database/connect.db.php');` or `require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/database/connect.db.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of your `include_path` in php.ini or your local config (via `.htaccess` for apache is another way to do it. If you add the path to `demo` to the `include_path` setting, then:

```
include('includes/database/connect.db.php');
```

or

```
require_once('includes/database/connect.db.php');
```

Will work from any file or sub folder.

Another way to do this is to include a single bootstrap file that has all the settings (i.e. not just your database ones) in your scripts.

A better way to do this is to route all your requests through a Front Controller that does anythign setup/teardown you need on every request. See [PHP Front Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053285/php-frontcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

you can define a constant in every file ... which defines the root folder you have

```
define('root', 'demo/');
```

and do

```
 require(root.'includes/database/connect.db.php');
```

and this will work fine with any file you want to require